# C: A safer way to check buffer in function and append to it?

Tags: c, pointers, strcat, error-checking, arrays

I have a function of which I need to return the time for another logging function, and it looks like this:

```
//put time in to buf, format 00:00:00\0
void gettimestr(char buf[9]) {
  if(strlen(buf) != 9) { //experimental error checking
    fprintf(stderr, "Buf appears to be %d bytes and not 9!\n", strlen( buf ));
  }
  time_t cur_time;
  time(&cur_time);
  struct tm *ts = localtime(&cur_time);
  sprintf(buf, "%02d:%02d:%02d",
        ts->tm_hour,
        ts->tm_min,
        ts->tm_sec );
  strncat(buf, "\0", 1);
}
```

Now I guess the main problem is checking if the buffer is long enough, sizeof() returns a pointer size and strlen seems to randomly return 0 or something such as 12 on two different calls.

My first question is, how would I be able to detect the size of the buffer safely, is it possible?

My other question is, is accepting buf[9] a favourable method or should I accept a pointer to a buffer, and use strcat() instead of sprintf() to append the time to it? sprintf makes it easier for padding zeros to the time values, although it seems to only accept a character array and not a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function assumes that the buffer being passed in already contains a null-terminated string with 9 characters. That doesn't make sense.

The proper way would be to request the size as an argument:

```
void gettimestr(char *buf, int bufferSize) {
```

and use snprintf:

```
snprintf(buf, bufferSize, "%02dx....", ....);<sub>*</sub>
```

<strike>And terminate the string since snprintf won't do that if you exceed the limit:</strike>

```
buf[bufferSize-1] = 0;
```

You can call your function like this:

```
char buffer[16];
gettimestr(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

There is no other way to determine the size. This isn't Java where an array knows its size. Passing a `char *` will simply send a pointer down to the function with no further information, so your only way to get the size of the buffer is by requiring the caller to specify it.

(EDIT: snprintf should always terminate the string properly, as pointed out in the comments.)

Comment: My understanding was fairly limited in this until now, thank you for making the clarifications. I also discovered in the mean time that strftime can be an alternative to manual snprintf although I like this better.

Comment: Adding the terminator is unnecessary - `snprintf()` *always* properly terminates the string (as long as the buffer length is at least 1).

Comment: @caf: True. I think I was burned once by a non-compliant implementation of snprintf.

Comment: @caf: Good catch, implemented that as well.

Answer (score 0):

@EboMike is right. Just to complement his answer, you could check the buffer with:

```
void gettimestr(char *buf, int bufferSize) {
    if (!buf) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Null buffer\n");
        return;
    }

 // rest of the code

 }
```

Comment: In the end this is the main checking I need to do on the buffer, the caller can do any number of mistakes which I shouldn't need to check for in this function. Thank you.